# Google App Engine Cloud SQL Exception: Invalid connection id. Error Code: 1007

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have an exception being thrown intermittently, when a cron task I have set up tries to access Google App Engine's Cloud SQL instance:

: [EL Info]: 2013-10-07 07:30:17.111--UnitOfWork(26414416)--Communication failure detected when attempting to perform read query outside of a transaction. Attempting to retry query. Error was: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.internal.SQLUnknownConnectionIdException: Invalid connection id.
Error Code: 1007

This does not seem happen when I call the same controller from the address bar, only intermittently from the cron task.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.internal.SQLUnknownConnectionIdException: Invalid connection id.

If you are using a connection pool, By default the CLOUD SQL connections gets purged exactly after 15 minutes. We decided to do away with connection pooling.

In Hibernate we did the following config and we no longer have the issue.

property name = "hibernate.connection.pool_size" value = "0"